# Does 'mousedown' event is supported in react-native?

Tags: react-native, mousedown

Does react native supports mousedown events ? if yes how i can use them ? I have been trying to add it to close a tray when user clicks anywhere on window.

Answer (score 0):

Check this out [https://reactnative.dev/docs/gesture-responder-system.html[enter](https://reactnative.dev/docs/gesture-responder-system.html%5Benter) link description here][1](https://reactnative.dev/docs/gesture-responder-system.html)

```
 <View onStartShouldSetResponder={() => true}
          onResponderStart={calledWhenTheTouchStarts}>
    
        <Text>Press Me!</Text>
    
    </View>
```